# Polymorphism, packages,

Tags: java

Hi everyone I am doing my homework and I got stuck so I need a bit of feedback.

I have a abstract class Gear and enum type Info in one package, then I have InfoTest which uses the assert and junit test to test the correctness of the Gear and the Info.

Problem is in the InfoTest. I have `Info g = some Value;` and then `g.getWeight()` which method is in the Gear class and I can't access the getWeight() method from InfoTest through Info object.

So I was wondering whether there is a way to access getWeight() with an Info object from InfoTest or my teacher has made a mistake. Thaks.

OKKKKKKKKKKK here is some code sample.

> public abstract class Gear {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * weight stores the weight of the item in kg
>  */
> protected int weight;
>
> /**
>  * code store the code for the item (bedding, food, medical or sanitary, but it is better to use array.
>  */
> protected char code;
>
> /**getWeight gets the weight of the item.
>  * 
>  * @return weight
>  */        
> public int getWeight() {
>     return weight;
> }
>
> /**setWeight sets the weight for the item
>  * 
>  * @param weight 
>  */
> public void setWeight(int weight) {
>     this.weight = weight;
> }
>
> /**getCode() gets the code of the item.
>  * 
>  * @return code
>  */
> public char getCode() {
>     return code;
> }
>
> /**setCode sets the code of the item.
>  * 
>  * @param code 
>  */
> public void setCode(char code) {
>     this.code = code;
> } }
> ```
>
> public enum Info {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * BLANKETS represent the blankets.
>  */
> BLANKETS,
>
> /**
>  * PILLOWS represent the pillows 
>  */
> PILLOWS,
>
> /**
>  * FOOD represent the food
>  */
> FOOD,
>
> /**
>  * MEDKIT represent the medical kit.
>  */
> MEDKIT,
>
> /**
>  * OXYGEN represent the oxygen 
>  */
> OXYGEN,
>
> /**
>  * NAPKINS represent the napkins.
>  */
> NAPKINS,
>
> /**
>  * SICKNESSBAG represent the sickness bags.
>  */
> SICKNESSBAG
>  }
> ```

```
> public class InfoTest {  
      /**
>      * Test of getWeight() method, of class Info. 
>      */
>     @Test
>     public void testGetWeight() {
>       System.out.print("\tChecking weights in Info");
>       Info g = Info.BLANKETS;
>       final int expectedValue1 = 2;
>       assertEquals(expectedValue1, g.getWeight()); }
> 
> }
```

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier to follow you're question if you'd just post your code.

Comment: Please include some code as it makes it almost impossible to figure out what the problem actually is just by describing it

Comment: Hard to understand what is going on without some code. Please post the pertinent sections of the classes and test.

Comment: Would be helpful to paste the code in, could be a private method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Info is an enumerated class, it does not have access to the Gear class at the moment. Its very difficult to work out exactly what the scope of your homework is.

Something like this...
Firstly make another class which extends your abstract class (something like SubGear)

```
public SubGear extends Gear
```

In this class have a constructor which takes in the Info object and also populates the fields from the Gear class like this:

```
public SubGear (Info info, int weight, char code){
    this.code = code;
    this.weight= weight;
    this.info = info
}

public void setInfo(Info info){
     this.info = info;
}

public Info getInfo(){
    return info;
}
```

Then in your test create a new SubGear object in order to access the getWeight as you require

Comment: How exactly would I create a constructor so that the enum relates to the gear, I have move the enum into the gear and the constructor is something like Gear() {  Info }

Comment: What exactly is the homework question? Its hard to know what you want to do unless we know that. Like are you trying to test the weight of blankets?

Comment: well the homework is more complex what I am I need to do is to have access to the g.getWeight(), because at the moment I don't have.